# Pass variable from .each loop to if statement within function

Tags: jquery, var

I'm a novice at Jquery/Javascript programming so please be gentle ;)

The function below checkes if a radiobutton from a specific group is selected. However I can't get the:

> var checkifonechecked = true;

to be passed to the if statement. It returns a Uncaught ReferenceError: checkifonechecked is not defined. How can I pass this var?

```
function stap3() {
$('input[name=ostap2]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var checkifonechecked = true;
    }
});
if(checkifonechecked){  
        $('#stap1, #stap2, #stap4, #stap5, #stap6, #stap7').hide();
        $('#stap3').show();
    } else {
        alert('neen'); }
}
```

Many thanx for any assistance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you are declaring your `checkifonechecked` variable inside an anonymous function (AKA a lambda). Once the anonymous function has ended, the variable no longer exists, so attempting to use it in the `stap3` function will fail with an "Uncaught ReferenceError" as you describe.

You need to declare your variable somewhere it's guaranteed to execute (e.g. the beginning of your `stap3` function), like so:

```
function stap3() {
    // DECLARE your variable outside the anonymous function.
    var checkifonechecked = false;

    $('input[name=ostap2]').each(function()  // This is the anonymous function.
    {
        if (this.checked) {
            // ASSIGN a value to your variable.
            checkifonechecked = true;
        }
    });

    if(checkifonechecked)
    {  
        $('#stap1, #stap2, #stap4, #stap5, #stap6, #stap7').hide();
        $('#stap3').show();
    } 
    else
    {
        alert('neen'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx to all people that anwsered ! All anwsers are more or less the same so I just choose this one to be the correct anwser!

Comment: No, Javascript doesn't have block scope, it has function scope. The variable doesn't exist only inside the `if` statement, it exist only inside the function.

Comment: @Guffa Sorry, you're quite right. I've edited my answer to make it clear that it's because the declaration is never being executed.

Comment: Declarations are always executed, even if they are inside code blocks that aren't executed. Every declaration inside the function is executed before the code in the function starts.

Comment: @Guffa Sorry, you're quite right (and very patient too!). I've updated to make it clear that it's because the variable is locally-scoped to the lambda. I've learnt something today :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to check how many are actually checked. There's really no need for the each statement or the variable

```
function stap3() {
   if($('input[name=ostap2]:checked').length){  
        $('#stap1, #stap2, #stap4, #stap5, #stap6, #stap7').hide();
        $('#stap3').show();
    } else {
        alert('neen'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: However this one is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

You're checking a variable that is declared in a different scope. You'll need to declare the variable in a higher scope:

```
function stap3() {
    var checkifonechecked = false;
    $('input[name=ostap2]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) checkifonechecked = true;
    });

    if (checkifonechecked) {
        $('#stap1, #stap2, #stap4, #stap5, #stap6, #stap7').hide();
        $('#stap3').show();
    } else {
        alert('neen');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of checkifonechecked, you need to move it to the stap3 function

```
function stap3() {
    var checkifonechecked = false;
    $('input[name=ostap2]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            checkifonechecked = true;
        }
    });

    if (checkifonechecked) {
        $('#stap1, #stap2, #stap4, #stap5, #stap6, #stap7').hide();
        $('#stap3').show();
    } else {
        alert('neen');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the HTML part (The section that contains the form), also, if you defined a variable as global, then, do not repeat (var checkifonechecked = true) just use (checkifonechecked  = true).

Now, for resource saving, break the loop once the selected checkbox found, because only one of them can be checked you don't need to see other checkboxes if selected one was found.